# javascript jquery find left position of element in horizontal scroll container

Tags: javascript, jquery, overflow, horizontal-scrolling

I have a overflow:auto container that spans 400% width of the document window. Therefore I have a horizontal scrollbar on my page. I also have multiple div's inside this container with different left positions. I need to get the left position of each container as I click on them. I use $(this).offset().left but that gives me the left offset of the container div which is 0px and I've used $(this).position().left but that gives me the same thing.... any suggestions?

Markup looks like this:

```
<div id='scroll'>
 <div id='content'>
   <div class='container' rel='1'></div>
   <div class='container' rel='2'></div>
   <div class='container' rel='3'></div>
   <div class='container' rel='4'></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

css

```
#scroll{
   position:absolute;
   width:100%;
   height:95%;
   overflow:auto;
   }
#content{
   float:left;
   height:100%;
}
.container{
   height:100%;
   float:left;
   }
```

jquery

```
 var iMaxSize = $(".container").size();
 $("#content").css({width: $(document).width()*iMaxSize +'px' });
 $(".container").css({width: $("#content").width()/iMaxSize +'px' });
```

Comment: Could we see the markup used for it?

Comment: @kinakuta - see OP for markup

Comment: This is hard to test because you have .container in your CSS but not in your HTML. By the sounds of it when you click, you're clicking on the parent because it's "on top of" the child elements... is this the case?

Comment: Yeah, offset().left should be working here. Offset here returns the left position of the element with respect to the document.

Comment: ... in reply to your question on my post, hit me up via email (dave@desmoinesfreelancer.com) to talk more about jquery dragging functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since for some reason I still can't get .offset() to work the way it should, or scrollLeft(). I just decided to do this a very round about way.

```
 $('.container').click(function(){
     var num = parseInt( $(this).attr('rel') );
     var left = $('.container').width() * num-1;
     var top  = $('.container').css('top');
     //do something with these values
 });
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the scroll position in the container element like this;

```
$('#container .element').offset().left - $('#container').offset().left + $('#container').scrollLeft();
```

See JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/danied/x20yqw7c/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `position()` instead of offset if you having trouble with offset.
Use width() of the object your scrolling to account for it.
Of course you can change the selector types to use ids or whatever fits your situation.

```
$('.class for container div')
     .animate( { scrollLeft: 
         $('.class for you want to scroll to').position().left - 
         $('.class for you want to scroll to').width() }
     ,'slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try something like this...

```
$('#id').width();
```

Comment: How would width() give me the left offset of an element?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it myself before, but I imagine it works similarly to scrollTop - take a look at [scrollLeft()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollLeft/) One thing you'll need to do is find the starting scrollLeft position of the element before scrolling occurred and cache it - then subtract that from the new scrollLeft position obtained after scrolling.

**edit** Wait, offset() isn't working? It should be working.