# How can all div auto scroll reverse on mouse-leave

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, mousewheel

On mouse hover parent div width extend to 100% and user can scroll child div 1 to 4. Suppose user scrolls to fourth child div and same time mouse leave then parent div width shrink to 50% as default but I expect that time first child comes in view by scrolling all div's four(current) to first. I tried something below but it not scrolls. So please can suggest solution for this so all div auto scroll back on mouse-leave.

html

```js
    var current = 0;
    var ScrollX_pixelPer = 15.05;
    $('.homePage-scrolling-wrapper').on("mousewheel", function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var delta = ScrollX_pixelPer*(parseInt(e.originalEvent.deltaY)/33);
     current += delta;
     $(this).scrollLeft(current);
    });
    
    $('.homePage-scrolling-wrapper').hover(function () {
     $('.homePage-staticSection').animate({'margin-left' : "-45%"});
     $(this).animate({'width' : "100%"});
     $(this).find('*').removeClass('to-right');
    }, 
    function () {
     $('.homePage-staticSection').animate({'margin-left' : "0"});
     $(this).animate({'width' : "50vw"});
     $(this).children().first().addClass('to-right');
    });
```

```css
body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
*{box-sizing: border-box;}
.homePage-container,
.homePage-scrolling-wrapper {
 display: flex;
 display: -webkit-flex;
}
.homePage-staticSection,
.homePage-scrolling-wrapper {
 width: 50vw;
 height: 100vh;
 border: 1px solid red;
}
.homePage-scrolling-wrapper {
 flex-wrap: nowrap;
 overflow-x: hidden;
 -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
 scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
 scroll-behavior: smooth;
 z-index: 4;
 cursor: ew-resize;
}
.scrolling-item {
 min-width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 scroll-snap-align: center;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}
.scrolling-item:nth-child(odd) {
 background: #1D5D95;
}
.scrolling-item:nth-child(even) {
 background: #CCCCCC;
}
      
.to-right {
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="homePage-container">
  <div class="homePage-staticSection"><h2>left box<h2></div>
  <div class="homePage-scrolling-wrapper">
  <div class="scrolling-item"><h2>Item-01</h2></div>
  <div class="scrolling-item"><h2>Item-02</h2></div>
  <div class="scrolling-item"><h2>Item-03</h2></div>
  <div class="scrolling-item"><h2>Item-04</h2></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide codepen for same so we can see your issue.

Comment: Please check this link. - https://codepen.io/ramesh_a/pen/poJaNyR

Comment: I found solution from here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400076/javascript-jquery-find-left-position-of-element-in-horizontal-scroll-container --From my jquery I removed- $(this).find('*').removeClass('to-right'); and replaced this- $(this).animate({scrollLeft: $('.scrolling-item').position().left - $('.scrolling-item').width()},'slow'); with $(this).children().first().addClass('to-right'); and it done.